# How to jump from cider-error buffer to the repl buffer?

Tags: clojure, cider

In clojure cider `repl`, when some code goes wrong, I have to `C-b k`, kill the cider-error buffer, `C-x o` switch back to the repl buffer. Is there a shortcut/function to jump back to the `repl` buffer directly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just press `q` in the `*cider-error*` buffer and you'll be back in the REPL.